# How to convert date string to epoch timestamp with the OS X BSD `date` command?

Tags: macos, date

I have a date string in the following format `Jul 27 23:59:59 2016 GMT` and I need to convert it to the equivalent epoch timestamp with the OS X BSD `date` command.

GNU `date` has a nice `-d`/`--date=STRING` argument:

```
$ date -d "Jul 27 23:59:59 2016 GMT" +'%s'
1469663999
```

The BSD `date` command on OSX sadly has no such option.

`date -j -f "<FORMAT>" "Jul 27 23:59:59 2016 GMT" +'%s'` seems to be the way to go, but I can't find the write format string. [Apple's man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) states:

```
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"

can be used to parse the output from date and express it in Epoch time.
```

But that doesn't appear to be true:

```
$ date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"
Failed conversion of ``Wed 13 Jul 2016 11:17:49 BST'' using format ``%a %b %d %T %Z %Y''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
        [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

How can I convert a date string in this format to an epoch timestamp with the OS X BSD `date` command?

---

I can't seem to get a version out of `date`, but I'm on OS X `10.11.5` (El Capitan) if that's significant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Wed Jul 13 11:30:27 BST 2016" +"%s"
1468405827
```

I worked that out by telling `date` to output in the same format as you were using:

```
date -j +"%a %b %d %T %Z %Y"
```

Comment: I found that I needed to add the -u option when calling the date command in order to convert to UTC, otherwise it was using the timezone of my local machine and throwing the timestamp off.

Answer (score 5):

Your `date` command is outputting the date in the following format:

```
Wed 13 Jul 2016 11:17:49 BST (Format sequence is: "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z")
```

and you're trying to parse it with an expression to match the following format:

```
Wed Jul 13 11:17:49 BST 2016 (Format sequence is: "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y")
```

Resulting in:

> Failed conversion of **``Wed 13 Jul 2016 11:17:49 BST''** using format **``%a %b %d %T %Z %Y''**

So, basically, you need to change the format sequence in your command with:

```
$ date -j -f "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z" "`date`" +"%s"
```

In order to match the `Wed 13 Jul 2016 11:17:49 BST` format that your `date` command is outputting by default.

To use a custom date based on the same format:

```
 $ date -j -f "%a %d %b %Y %T %Z" "Wed 13 Jul 2016 11:17:49 BST" +"%s"
```

Some references on what [some of] the format string sequences mean:

- **%a**     locale's abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Sun)
- **%d**     day of month (e.g., 01)
- **%b**     locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)
- **%Y**     year
- **%T**     time; same as %H:%M:%S
- **%Z**     alphabetic time zone abbreviation (e.g., EDT)

Comment: Thanks for your help. That format did come from Apple's man page, so I assume the docs are out of date. Do you know if the full range of date symbols for the format are documented anywhere?

Comment: Mark Setchell was first out of the gate with the correct answer, so I'm going to give him the tick, but I've upvoted this. Thanks for the complete response.

Comment: Sure. Btw, regarding the full doc for the formats, you can `man strftime` or, if unavailable, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

Answer (score 5):

I ran into an issue trying to convert a similar `datetime` to `epoch`. Thought I would put this out here for this format as well.
`date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2018-01-30 15:58:50" "+%s"`
`1517349530`

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way:

```
$ python -c 'import time
> print int(time.time())'
1468406482
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this converts the _current_ date, not an arbitrary one. Using Python is not a bad idea actually if you require portability between Linux and MacOS (modulo the complications of Python 2 vs Python 3).